# How to insert data from text file in database one word per row

Tags: php, mysql

Test.text

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl,...
```

Is there anyway possible to insert each one to each row in database?

```
1 abc
2 def
...
```

Any suggest?

Comment: Yes there is, but what are you trying to accomplish?  Is this homework?

Comment: No...I just want to know. Can't I ?

Comment: suggestion is this: open the file - read the file, parse the content, insert the records.

Comment: I just want to lear to insert data from text file by using PHP

Comment: this is actually trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you can do that with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$var = explode(",", $file);
```

The `$var` variable will be a array containing, in this case, 4 positions(0,1,2, 3) with this('abc','def','ghi','jkl').

No you can do a `foreach` inserting the values on your table:

```
foreach($var as $x)
{
//YOUR INSERT GOES HERE. PASSING THE $x TO YOUR QUERY
}
```

Just complementing Breland answer, you could also do this directly with MySQL like this?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/test.txt' INTO TABLE test TERMINATED BY ','
```

And if necessary, you can add this: `LINES STARTING BY 'xxx'` to define from where the insert will begin. It is useful in case you want to avoid some lines on your file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the commas are always the separator for values, you don't even need PHP.

Check out the page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

An example you can start with is

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\path\data.txt' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

Comment: Yes this may be fairly complicated for the novice. It works very well though

Comment: Yeah, but I think that could at least have the `TERMINATED BY ','` since she is working with a `CSV` file

Comment: because then you could simple json_decode($a,true) and now it is an array ..... foreach($arr as $b) mysql_query(INSERT into.....)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the php `file_get_contents();` function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Look at the php `explode();` function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

This will get your string into an array which you can then insert into your database.

You can execute a MySQL `INSERT` query using the `mysqli_*` functions in php.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: I did, your answer is good and with sources, what is important. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how big the Text.txt file is but if its small-ish then you can do it like:

```
<?php 
$text = file_get_contents('Test.txt');
$arrayOfTxt = explode(',',$text);

foreach($arrayOfTxt as $value){
    //Insert trim($value)
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = fopen('test.txt', 'r');   
$csv_array = fgetcsv($file);   
foreach ($csv_array as $csv_data){
            //Do your insertion code here.

 }
```